# Visual Studio C# Debug vs Release and Compilation debug="false"

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012

I have confused myself and am seeking clarification after reading and not finding an clear answer, that or I'm too sleep deprived to "get it":

I am testing Javascript/CSS bundling on my local machine using Visual Studio 2012.

I can not get this to work without having web.config

```
    <compilation debug="false"...
```

or setting

```
    protected void Application_Start()
    {
    BundleTable.EnableOptimizations = true;
    ...
```

So if I set the debug="false" then Visual Studio complains "The page cannot be run in debug mode... "

Am I missing a fundamental concept?  I want to run a test or two with the Bundling/Minification on.  Do I have to manually set either of the above two settings? Why does this not work automatically when I have `debug="true"` but use `Ctrl+F5`?

It seems like a pain to have to manually turn on/off the `<compilation debug="true"` setting when I want to see this feature on my local machine.

Am I missing something?

Comment: What's wrong with including `BundleTable.EnableOptimizations = true;`? You could wrap it in an `#if DEBUG` if you only want it hardcoded like this while debugging.

Comment: @TimS. I don't want it on 100% of the time, and yes I was thinking of wrapping it in that type of conditional operator, but I was unsure if that was sort of "hacking" my way around functionality that I am not understanding.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding:

```
 BundleTable.EnableOptimizations = (!HttpContext.Current.IsDebuggingEnabled);
```

This gives you the benefit of including the full version of js while in debug mode and a minified version when in release mode.

Are you sure the prompt you are getting when you include compilation debug="false"... is not a warning such as ..."debugging is not turned on. Do you want to enable debugging?" type prompt?

Comment: Yes, it is exactly a "Debugging Not Enabled" dialog when I set the `debug="false"`.  Your solution is the same as setting the `debug="false"`, as it continues to use each individual file when running, even with a `Ctrl + F5`

Comment: These options are mutually exclusive. You can set Debug=true and EnableOptimizations=false.

Comment: Yes, but I guess what I wanted to accomplish was a dynamic way of enabling the batching/minimization without hard coding `debug="true"` or the `EnableOptimization` when working on my local computer.  Then if I used `Ctrl + F5` it would batch/minimize the files for example.

Comment: Sorry, its been a while but I thought maybe you could use directives for this--> #if (DEBUG)...#else...#endif